# Closed Operators: Spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider operators:
$$T:\mathcal{D}(T)\to\mathcal{H}$$

Suppose one has:
$$T=\overline{T}=T^{**}$$

Then it may happen:
$$\sigma(T)=\varnothing,\mathbb{C}$$

What are examples?

Comment: The spectrum of a bounded operator on a Banach space (over $\mathbb{C}$) is always non-empty, so you need to look at unbounded operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{H}=L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ and define $L=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dt}$ on the domain of absolutely continuous $f \in \mathcal{H}$ with $f' \in \mathcal{H}$ and $f(0)=f(2\pi)=0$.

This operator is $L$ closed, densely-defined, symmetric and has $\sigma(L)=\mathbb{C}$.

It should be noted that adding the constant function $1$ to the domain of $L$ results in a  selfadjoint operator.

An operator with no spectrum: Consider $L=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dt}$ on the domain of absolutely continuous functions $f \in \mathcal{H}$ for which $f' \in \mathcal{H}$ and $f(0)=0$. To see that this has empty spectrum, note that the following equation has a unique solution $f$ for all complex $\lambda$ and $g \in \mathcal{H}$:
$$
                       \frac{1}{i}f'-\lambda f = g,\;\;\; f(0)=0.
$$

Comment: But that one has full spectrum not empty ;)

Comment: I mean from an earlier answer of yours it must not be symmetric either...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I reversed that in my head. I'll supply the other example, too.

Comment: Hey btw thanks to your help I finally finished: Positive Operators: Definition? :)

Comment: @Freeze_S : What did you finish? Are congratulations in order? What is your question about Positive Operators?

Comment: It was wether for unbounded normal operators it holds: $\langle\sigma(N)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(N)}$ Yes, congratulations are in order. ^^ Thanks for the enlightening proofs of yours! :)

Comment: Remember that one: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/822319/79762

Comment: @Freeze_S : Congratulations!!!!! And thank you very much for telling me that I've help in some way in this process. That means something significant to me. You're welcome for the help; pay it forward.

Comment: Absolute continuity is to have a Lebesgue integrable derivative?

Comment: And how to implement the boundary condition on equivalence classes? (I guess by some sort of limiting argument on continuous function.)

Comment: For the unrestricted domain for $L$, you'll notice that $(Lf,g)-(f,Lg)$ is an integral of absolutely integrable functions, which can be written as a limit of $\frac{1}{i}f\overline{g}|_{0}^{2\pi}$, thereby giving existence for the limits of the right side as your approach $0$ and $2\pi$. From that you can choose specific $g$ to get existence of limits for $f$, including $f(0+0),f(2\pi-0)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{D}(L_{\mbox{unrestricted}})$. I've been helping someone else with this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012104/limit-point-limit-circle-and-self-adjointness/1012535#1012535