# Why is the maximal domain $D_\text{max}$ of a Sturm-Liouville operator defined the way it is?

Tags: sturm-liouville, self-adjoint-operators, unbounded-operators, absolute-continuity

Given a Sturm-Liouville type operator which acts on functions on the interval $(a,b)$

$$T:= \frac{1}{w(x)}\left(-\frac{d}{dx}\left[p(x) \frac{d}{dx}\right]+q(x)\right)$$

where $w$, $p^{-1}$ and $q \in L_{\text{loc}}(a,b)$ and are real valued, we define its maximal domain as

$$
 D_{\text{max}}:=\big \{f \in L^2_w(a,b) : f,pf'\in \text{AC}_{\text{loc}}(a,b), \quad Tf\in L^2_w(a,b) \big \}
$$

Where $L^2_w(a,b)$ is the space of square integrable functions on $(a,b)$ with weight $w$.

I am trying to understand the motivation for defining the maximal domain as above.

I understand the requirement that $f$ and $Tf\in L^2_w(a,b)$, since we want $T$ to be an endomorphism (so we can apply the Hilbert space theory of $L^2_w(a,b)$).

However I am not totally certain why we ask for **absolute** continuity of $f$ and $pf'$.

I surmise that it's because it is the weakest assumption needed to make the derivatives $f'$ and $(pf')'$ Lebesgue integrable (e.g. see [Lebesgues fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions)), which is needed in order to perform integration by parts as to investigate the symmetry of operator $T$. i.e.

\begin{align}
\langle Tf,g \rangle &= \int_a^b \left(-\frac{d}{dx}\left[p(x) \frac{df}{dx}\right]+q(x)f\right)\cdot\overline{g} \quad dx=\text{boundary terms } +  \langle f,Tg \rangle
\end{align}

Does this seem reasonable? I am just concerned I am over looking something, and the texts I am following (Zettls Sturm-Liouville Theory and Naimarks Linear Differential Operators) don't seem to mention why the AC condition is required.

EDIT:

An equivalent definition we could give of $D_{\text{max}}$ is that its the domain of the maximal operator, however I'd be happier with a more apriori definition though, as the maximal domain seems to be introduced in the referenced texts before the introduction of the minimal or maximal operators.

Comment: Is this the same as the "maximal domain" mentioned [here](https://am.math.cas.cz/full/60/3/am60_3_5.pdf)?

Comment: Almost certainly, one of the authors of that paper, Zettl, is the one whose text I am following.

Comment: I'm very rusty on this stuff, but it seems that it is defined as the domain of the operator adjoint, which turns out to be that expression.

Comment: [DBP says](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1012535/252672) "it turns out".

Comment: Thanks for linking that - DBP is very helpful on the stackexchange.  I suppose this could be taken as a satisfactory definition of $D_{\text{max}}$, given that the adjoint of all extensions of the minimal operator are restrictions of the maximal operator. I'd be happier with a more apriori definition though, as the maximal domain seems to be introduced in the referenced texts before the introduction of the minimal or maximal operators.

Comment: If you define $T_{min}$ on $C_{c}^{\infty}(a,b)$, which consists of all $C^{\infty}$ functions that are compactly supported in $(a,b)$, and if $T_{min}$ is symmetric, then $T_{max}=T_{min}^*$. The smaller the graph of a restriction of $T$, the larger the graph of its adjoint, assuming, of course that $T_{min}$ is densely-defined so that an adjoint makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical minimal domain for $T$ would consist of $C^{\infty}_{c}(a,b)$, which consists of infinitely differentiable functions that are compactly supported in $(a,b)$. The minimal operator $T_m$ with this domain then gives rise to the maximal operator $T_{M}=T_m^*$, which is the adjoint of the minimal operator. This works because $T_{m}$ is symmetric on its domain. So the maximal operator $T_M$ is an extension of $T_m$, but it is maximal because the graph of $T_M$ is the orthogonal complement of the graph of $T_m$ in $L^2(a,b)\times L^2(a,b)$. Defining it in this way basically ensures that the maximal operator is the largest closed extension of $T_m$ in $L^2(a,b)\times L^2(a,b)$. This keeps the discussion in a Hilbert space. You could extend beyond the Hilbert space into distributions, but this keeps the discussion in a Hilbert space. The maximal domain has no endpoint restrictions, unlike the minimal domain where functions vanish near the endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer DBP, this is one way to define the maximal domain and certainly highlights why it is the biggest domain in which you would work on when keeping the image of $T$ inside of $L^2(a,b)$. I was looking for some reasoning which motivated each of the requirements in the definition of $D_\text{max}$, rather than showing the definition is equivalent to the domain of the largest closed extension of the minimal operator. However your answer is certainly enough motivation for the definition of $D_\text{max}$ in and of itself.

Comment: @valcofadden : There are many advantages of this methodology. It is particularly noteworthy that if $T$ is symmetric and densely-defined, then the closure $T^c$ exists and satisfies $T \preceq T^c \preceq T^*=(T^c)^*$. (I am using $\preceq$ to indicate a graph inclusion, meaning that one operator is an extension of the other.)